# generating frame labels automatically

Tags: labels

may i seek your help again? i was wondering if you can help me modify a little bit your `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` macro in "Commands in frame labels, generating frame labels automatically" so that the output of MWE 8 is the same as the output of MWE 7?

MWE 7:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\includeonlyframes%    
{%    
myframelabelprefix-0.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.2,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.1.2,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.1.2,%    
}

\setcounter{section}{0}    
\setcounter{subsection}{0}    
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-0.0.0]{Outline}    
\tableofcontents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 1.0.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-1.0.0]{Frame 1.0.0 Title}    
Frame 1.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 1.1.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-1.1.0]{Frame 1.1.0 Title}    
Frame 1.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.1 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-1.1.1]{Frame 1.1.1 Title}    
Frame 1.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}    

\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.2 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-1.1.2]{Frame 1.1.2 Title}    
Frame 1.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 2.0.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-2.0.0]{Frame 2.0.0 Title}    
Frame 2.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 2.1.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-2.1.0]{Frame 2.1.0 Title}    
Frame 2.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 2.1.1 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-2.1.1]{Frame 2.1.1 Title}    
Frame 2.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 2.1.2 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-2.1.2]{Frame 2.1.2 Title}    
Frame 2.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 3.0.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-3.0.0]{Frame 3.0.0 Title}    
Frame 3.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 3.1.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-3.1.0]{Frame 3.1.0 Title}    
Frame 3.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.1 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-3.1.1]{Frame 3.1.1 Title}    
Frame 3.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.2 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-3.1.2]{Frame 3.1.2 Title}    
Frame 3.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\end{document}

MWE 8:

\documentclass{beamer}

\includeonlyframes%

{%    
myframelabelprefix-0.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.2,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.1.2,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.1.2,%    
}

\setcounter{section}{0}    
\setcounter{subsection}{0}    
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Outline}    
\tableofcontents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 1.0.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.0.0 Title}    
Frame 1.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 1.1.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.1.0 Title}    
Frame 1.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.1 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.1.1 Title}    
Frame 1.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.2 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.1.2 Title}    
Frame 1.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 2.0.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 2.0.0 Title}    
Frame 2.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 2.1.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 2.1.0 Title}    
Frame 2.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 2.1.1 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 2.1.1 Title}    
Frame 2.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 2.1.2 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 2.1.2 Title}    
Frame 2.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 3.0.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 3.0.0 Title}    
Frame 3.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 3.1.0 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 3.1.0 Title}    
Frame 3.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.1 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 3.1.1 Title}    
Frame 3.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.2 Title}

\begin{frame}[label=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 3.1.2 Title}    
Frame 3.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello! I suspect by "Commands in frame labels, generating frame labels automatically" you're referring to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431814/commands-in-frame-labels-generating-frame-labels-automatically) question? In that case you should [edit] and make it a link you can find instructions in the [help-center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links). Furthermore it's really hard to infer what you want help with. You should make your examples much smaller, and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I adapted my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431814/commands-in-frame-labels-generating-frame-labels-automatically/431971#431971) to your previous question to do what you want.

Again, with the new option `cmdlabel` commands can be used in the label name. And since you seem to want to use the same scheme for all labels, I also adapted `autolabel` to do the labeling in an easier way.

For both options `\edef` is used, so they only work with `\arabic`, but not `\alph` or alike.

Btw., your scheme has some problems:

If your have more then one frame per `\subsubsection`, a label will be given twice and you'll get a warning about this. Using such a label in `\includeonlyframes` will show both frames. I added an example in the code for *Frame 1.1.2*.

The counter for `\subsubsection`s is reset by `\subsection`, but not by `\section`. Therefore the label for e.g. *Frame 3.0.0* is not `myframelabelprefix-3.0.0` but rather `myframelabelprefix-3.0.2`. I changed the labels in `\includeonlyframes` accordingly and marked them in the code.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
% set label with automatic name
\newcommand*{\autolabelprefix}[1]{%
    \def\autolabel@prefix{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\autolabel@setlabel}[1]{%
    \setkeys{beamerframe}{label=#1}%
}
\define@key{beamerframe}{autolabel}[]{%
    \edef\@autolabel{\autolabel@prefix\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}%
    \expandafter\autolabel@setlabel\expandafter{\@autolabel}%
}

% set label with command
\newcommand*{\cmdlabel@setlabel}[1]{%
    \typeout{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX label: #1}%
    \setkeys{beamerframe}{label=#1}%
}
\define@key{beamerframe}{cmdlabel}{%
    \edef\@cmdlabel{#1}%
    \expandafter\cmdlabel@setlabel\expandafter{\@cmdlabel}%
}
\makeatother
\autolabelprefix{myframelabelprefix-}

\includeonlyframes%
{%    
myframelabelprefix-0.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.0.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-1.1.2,%    <-- double, both frames shown
myframelabelprefix-2.0.2,%    <-- changed
myframelabelprefix-2.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-2.1.2,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.0.2,%    <-- changed
myframelabelprefix-3.1.0,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.1.1,%    
myframelabelprefix-3.1.2,%    
}

\setcounter{section}{0}    
\setcounter{subsection}{0}    
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Outline}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Outline}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

\tableofcontents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 1.0.0 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 1.0.0 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.0.0 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 1.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 1.1.0 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 1.1.0 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.1.0 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 1.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.1 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 1.1.1 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.1.1 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 1.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.2 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 1.1.2 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.1.2 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 1.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

% this will produce a warning, because the label is the same
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 1.1.2 Title 2}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 1.1.2 Title 2}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

seocnd Frame in 1.1.2

Frame 1.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 2.0.0 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 2.0.0 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 2.0.0 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 2.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 2.1.0 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 2.1.0 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 2.1.0 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 2.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 2.1.1 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 2.1.1 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 2.1.1 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 2.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 2.1.2 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 2.1.2 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 2.1.2 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 2.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 3.0.0 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 3.0.0 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 3.0.0 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 3.0.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 3.1.0 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 3.1.0 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 3.1.0 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 3.1.0 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.1 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 3.1.1 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 3.1.1 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 3.1.1 Contents    
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.2 Title}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame 3.1.2 Title}    
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame 3.1.2 Title}    
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}

Frame 3.1.2 Contents    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi Mike, thank you very much. im currently going through your answer/code...you have been very helpful. --dennis

Comment: i have been asking all these queries because at the back of my mind, i wanted to be able to write latex/beamer files focused on content, equations and the like, and less focus on  labels. i wanted labels to be generated automatically and uniquely, so i can focus on the more important things. i hope others would find this useful also in their own work.

Comment: hi sir mike, thank you very much. i think your code works perfectly well. there is just one thing i do not understand in the code -- what is the meaning/significance of the "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"?

Comment: @beethovengg14 it's just a bit leftover test code. `\typeout` writes its argument to the log file. So there you will find some lines with `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX label: ` and the generated label name. You can remove the `\typeout...` line from the code, if you want.

Comment: thank you mike. i wish i had enough time to study pure TeX commands, since it seems that i can do so many things with the basic commands. sometimes LaTeX is not enough, i need to understand too the basic TeX commands. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

based on Mike's answer, i just did some very minor changes, but basically the idea is all here.

\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter

% set label with automatic name
\newcommand*{\autolabelprefix}[1]%
{%
\def\autolabel@prefix{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\autolabel@setlabel}[1]%
{%
\setkeys{beamerframe}{label=#1}%
}

\define@key{beamerframe}{autolabel}[]%
{%
\edef\@autolabel{\autolabel@prefix\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}%
\expandafter\autolabel@setlabel\expandafter{\@autolabel}%
}

% set label with command
\newcommand*{\cmdlabel@setlabel}[1]%
{%
\typeout{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX label: #1}%
\setkeys{beamerframe}{label=#1}%
}

\define@key{beamerframe}{cmdlabel}%
{%
\edef\@cmdlabel{#1}%
\expandafter\cmdlabel@setlabel\expandafter{\@cmdlabel}%
}

\makeatother

\autolabelprefix{myframelabelprefix-}

\includeonlyframes%
{%
myframelabelprefix-0.0.0,%
myframelabelprefix-1.0.0,%
myframelabelprefix-1.1.0,%
myframelabelprefix-1.1.1,%
myframelabelprefix-1.1.2,%
myframelabelprefix-1.1.3,%
myframelabelprefix-2.0.0,%
myframelabelprefix-2.1.0,%
myframelabelprefix-2.1.1,%
myframelabelprefix-2.1.2,%
myframelabelprefix-3.0.0,%
myframelabelprefix-3.1.0,%
myframelabelprefix-3.1.1,%
myframelabelprefix-3.1.2,%
myframelabelprefix-3.1.3,%
}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Outline}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 1.0.0 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 1.1.0 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.1 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.2 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

% this will produce a warning, because the label is the same
\subsubsection{Frame 1.1.3 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 2.0.0 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 2.1.0 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 2.1.1 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 2.1.2 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\section{Frame 3.0.0 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsection{Frame 3.1.0 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.1 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.2 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Frame 3.1.3 Title}
%\begin{frame}[autolabel]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
\begin{frame}[cmdlabel=myframelabelprefix-\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}]{Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Title}
Frame \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection} Contents
\end{frame}

\end{document}

we can now create a command environment function, say myframe, to define our own customized frames which will generate labels automatically and uniquely. thank you again Mike.

--dennis